# Surfacing the chatter UI to an external site

Tags: api, chatter

I know the Chatter API exists, which lets you get and set nearly any kind of Chatter data. My question is, is there the ability to just pick up the entire (or a piece of) the chatter UI and surface that in an external site, or do I have to write my own UI and use the Chatter API to try to create that functionality?

Edit: For clarity, what i'm looking for is an HTML/js/css snippet I could insert inline into my site, or something I can frame into my site.

Comment: Pretty vague, but: I **believe** that they announced at dreamforce that you will be (future #safeharbor) able to host/expose lightning components anywhere. There may already be standard chatter lightning components, or public components made by others.

Comment: There are standard chatter lightning components, so as soon as Lightning Out goes GA, this is very doable. That said, you still need to get an auth token since chatter is for authenticated users only.